# Cant run cypress tests in Chrome & Edge browsers(being manageed by organization)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cypress

I'm trying to run cypress tests using Cypress Test Runner in chrome & Edge browsers which are being managed by my organization. So I cant change much settings/chrome flags.

I'm getting this error with chrome browser.

> This browser was not launched through Cypress. Tests cannot run.

Any idea how to run my tests in these browsers?

[image]

Comment: How are you running the tests? Please add that info in your question.

Comment: Thanks. Im Using cypress test runner, have added to to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try doing this:

- Open the cypress app (Test Runner)
- Go to File -> View App Data
- Delete everything in here
- Close cypress and open it up again

If the above doesn't work out, you can check this link. It talks about some work-arounds.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/error-messages#Cypress-detected-policy-settings-on-your-computer-that-may-cause-issues

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right KB. Using Electron browser solved in my case

Answer (score 0):

Proxy Mode properties is set for Proxy settings in RegEdit, Hence its not allowing to run scripts on chrome/Edge.

Find machine or VDI's where you can get admin rights and remove above properties from RegEdit.